# Postgres Repeatable Read vs Selecting rows that are changed by another ongoing transaction

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, isolation-level

Let's say I have a set of select statements that query important field values in a for-loop.
The goal is to make sure that the rows are not updated by any other transaction so that this set of selects doesn't result in data that is out of date.

In theory, it seems that setting the transaction level to `repeatable read` should solve the problem. In this case, we can begin the transaction in the first select statement and then reuse the same transaction in this loop to make sure that updates are blocked until this transaction is committed.

Is there anything I am missing? Probably, there are some other ways to be sure that stale rows are not selected.

UPDATE: a bit more details

I have a series of queries like `select name from some_table where id = $id_param` and this `$id_param` is set in a for-loop.

I am worried, however, that this `name` field might be changed by another concurrent operation for some row or even get deleted. This would result in corrupted states for the final object.

It seems that based on the comment below, pessimistic locking could be the way to go i.e. using `...FOR UPDATE`, but I am not sure.

Comment: Reading a row will never block a concurrent update, no matter what the isolation level is. You have to use `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` for that. But that means that you have to keep a transaction open, which should never happen. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, just added more details in the OP

Comment: Yes, you'd have to lock. But why is it a problem if somebody modifies or deletes such a row?

Comment: The primary reason is that those multiple select statements in the for-loop update very important state-related fields. If the object they ultimately make is out of date then all further operations might be wrong

Comment: Yea locking is what you want. But I think the better question is why are you querying the same table multiple times in a loop? It would be more efficient and essentially solve your problem to query the table once to get all the rows that your loop is pulling, in a single query execution.

Comment: @J.D., my first query returns rows where one of the fields is an array of jsonb objects. Those fields have values like `#2` that need to be replaced with names based on a set of rules that is in another table. This is why I have to iterate over the rows and use that lookup table for each value

Comment: I too don't see the need for a loop. Sounds as if this could be achieved with a join (maybe with the help of some custom functions).

Comment: ^Agreed. This likely can be done via a `JOIN` or at least stitched back together on the application side (and only hitting each table once). But looping and hitting the database for each iteration is usually not a normal solution, is generally inefficient, and has other drawbacks such as concern with controlling concurrency (such as what your original question is on).

Comment: I understand. But someone could modify the data a split-second after your operation is done. How would that be different from someone modifying the data while your operation is running?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, you're doing it the wrong way.

Look for a way where all the updates can be done using a single update command.

you might need to use a temporary table and
update from it.

```
UPDATE  table_name  SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] FROM other_table WHERE condition
```